# How convert URI parameters into JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a params string:

```
program_id=11792&percentage=5
```

I want it converted it to standard JSON:

```
{"program_id":"117902", "percentage":"5"}
```

Comment: That params string doesn't *look* decoded

Comment: @Quentin sorry didn't really know what I was asking. I updated the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, if you didn't know, JSON !== JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### One liner:

```
var json = params.split('&').map(function(i) { return i.split('=');}).reduce(function(m,o){ m[o[0]] = o[1]; return m;},{});
```

---

#### A more complete solution:

```
params.split('&').map(function(i) { 
    return i.split('=');
}).reduce(function(memo, i) { 
    memo[i[0]] = i[1] == +i[1] ? parseFloat(i[1],10) : decodeURIComponent(i[1]); 
    return memo;
}, {});
```

- will parse numbers:

  `"no=2"` => `{ no: 2 }` compared to the previous version `{ no: "2" }`.
- will perform URI decoding:

  `"greeting=hello%3Dworld"` => `{ greeting: "hello world" }`

Comment: I like the general pattern, but this is a strange use of reduce.  This code, though simple, is hard to read because you smushed it onto 2 lines needlessly.

Comment: @Brandon this is a pretty common use of reduce and I suggest you handle numbers as well `m[o[0]] = o[1] == parseFloat(o[1],10) ? parseFloat(o[1], 10) : o[1];`

Comment: @megawac: Nice idea, I liked the compact x==+x to check if it's a number.

Comment: @megawac: Should it also try to figure out that `true` and `false` might not be strings?  It seems to be a slippery slope.

Comment: @CristiMihai: You might want to consider adding `decodeURIComponent` as well to turn this into a plain string first.

Comment: @megawac: Yes it does.  Try it.

Comment: Ah you're right I thought it did but second guessed myself there

Comment: @ScottSauyet: I added the decodeURIComponent too, as it seems a good idea, but not as a first step, as it might mess up the splitting.

Comment: Good point.  I'll update my answer too, although all the action is here.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, however, it doesn't check for any errors:

```
var url = "program_id=11792&percentage=5";
var parts = url.split("&");
var paramsObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
   var keyAndValue = parts[i].split("=");
   paramsObj[keyAndValue[0]] = paramsObj[keyAndValue[1]];
}
console.log(paramsObj); // here's your object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var convert = function(params) {
    return params.split("&").map(function(item) {
        return item.split("=");
    }).reduce(function(obj, pair) {
        obj[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        return obj;
    }, {});
};

convert("program_id=11792&percentage=5&name=Andrew%20Wei");
//=> Object {program_id: "11792", percentage: "5", name: "Andrew Wei"}
```

You can call `JSON.stringify` on the resulting object if you want a string and not an object.

Comment: Oops, beat to it.  See the same solution by @CristiMihai below

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a general purpose solution if you're interested:

https://github.com/gburghardt/cerealizer